# The 'else' in my if/else statement never happens - can someone explain why?

Tags: javascript

Just doing the codecademy course, everything works when I run the code except for this if/else statement. When it gets to that, no matter what I input for the userAnswer prompt, I just get the 'if' output. Can someone explain why? Been reading this thing 100x and the answer isn't jumping out at me. Thanks a ton.

```
var userAnswer = prompt("Do you want to race Bieber on stage?");

if(userAnswer="yes") {

    console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!")

} else {

    console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'")

}
```

Comment: `=` is for assigning values to variables and `==` is for comparing values. (and `===` is for comparing value AND type)

Comment: This could have been useful if the problem statement were well written. as it stands, no one will ever come across this question from Google because it doesn't contain information people would google for (No one is ever going to put into Google "the else in my if statement never happens can someone explain why?") they might have searched for: "equality check always returns false in JavaScript" (though that has its own issues.

Answer (score 5):

You're setting `userAnswer` instead of reading its state.

Change your conditional to

```
userAnswer === "yes"
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `if` test, use `===` to do comparison. `=` does assignment.

(You could also use `==`, but that's a partially broken version of `===`.)

Answer (score 0):

Change the if statement to

```
 userAnswer === "yes"
```

Comment: Why even bother answering when there are already up voted answers saying the same thing?

Comment: I obviously did not notice (old age i guess)

Answer (score 0):

You made a small mistake to check for condition you have to use double equal that is if(username = "yes") is wrong us if(username === "yes" )

```js
var userAnswer = prompt("Do you want to race Bieber on stage?");

if(userAnswer==="yes") {

console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!")
}

else {

console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'")
}
```